# ndsolve solution goes to zero for large domain

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve numerically the diffusion equation with absorbing boundary conditions on a finite domain. The initial condition is an approximation of a delta function centered in x0 with standard deviation sigma.

I find that changing the size of the domain slightly has a dramatic (non-physical) effect on the solution evaluated at a finite time. Why is this? Why don't I get a warning from Mathematica? This code reproduces the problem:

```
sigma = 1/32;
T = 10;
x0 = 1;
L = 24;
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[pn[x, t], {t, 1}] == 1/8 D[pn[x, t], {x, 2}], 
pn[0, t] == 0, pn[L, t] == 0, 
pn[x, 0] == 1/Sqrt[2 Pi sigma^2] Exp[-(x - x0)^2/(2 sigma^2)]}, 
pn[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, T}];
L = 26;
sol2 = NDSolve[{D[pn[x, t], {t, 1}] == 1/8 D[pn[x, t], {x, 2}], 
pn[0, t] == 0, pn[L, t] == 0, 
pn[x, 0] == 1/Sqrt[2 Pi sigma^2] Exp[-(x - x0)^2/(2 sigma^2)]}, 
pn[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, T}];
t = T;
GraphicsRow[{Plot[Evaluate[pn[x, t] /. sol1], {x, 0, 24}, 
PlotRange -> All], 
Plot[Evaluate[pn[x, t] /. sol2], {x, 0, 26}, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

On the left I plot the solution with domain size L=24, on the right I plot the solution with L=26. As you can see, the change is dramatic (notice the y axis values) and Mathematica produces no warning.

How can I solve this issue and be able to solve the equation numerically for L larger than 24?

[image]

Comment: Tip; Setting the variable of integration `t` to a numeric value with `t = T` messes things up when you (or I) recompute the solutions.  It's very inconvenient.  You can avoid needing such a workaround by solving for `pn` instead of `pn[x, t]` in your `NDSolve` calls.  Alternatively, you could use the code `pn[x, t] /. sol /. t -> T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have control the quality of the grid/mesh of the spatial variable. Either with `"MaxStepSize"`:

```
NDSolve[{D[ppn[x, t], {t, 1}] == 1/8 D[ppn[x, t], {x, 2}], 
  ppn[0, t] == 0, ppn[L, t] == 0, 
  ppn[x, 0] == 
   1/Sqrt[2 Pi sigma^2] Exp[-(x - x0)^2/(2 sigma^2)]}, ppn, {x, 0, 
  L}, {t, 0, T},
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MaxStepSize" -> 1}}]
```

or with `"MinPoints"`:

```
NDSolve[{D[ppn[x, t], {t, 1}] == 1/8 D[ppn[x, t], {x, 2}], 
  ppn[0, t] == 0, ppn[L, t] == 0, 
  ppn[x, 0] == 
   1/Sqrt[2 Pi sigma^2] Exp[-(x - x0)^2/(2 sigma^2)]}, ppn, {x, 0, 
  L}, {t, 0, T},
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MinPoints" -> Ceiling@L}}]
```